# getJSON - Can't use a variable into getJSON

Tags: jquery, getjson

I'm building a sync option for a shopping cart. If a user is logged in, it shows different prices ofcourse. I use this function to make sure the cart is also being updated after login or logout.

Problem: I want to use the `key.quantity` into the getJSON function to build up the cart again with the correct amount. How to manage this?

```
function sync() {
// Read LocalStorage
        try {
          var dataArray = JSON.parse(getLocalStorage('cartarray'));
        }
        catch (err) {
          var dataArray = null;
        }
        
        ary1 = dataArray.cartlines;
        
        var keys = Object.values(ary1);
        
        
        // Delete LocalStorage
        unsetLocalStorage('cartarray');
        
        var custom = null;
        for (var key of keys) {
            console.log(key);
            var quantity1 = key.quantity;

            $.getJSON("https://" + window.location.hostname + "/search/?sku=" + key.sku, {quantity1})

           .done(function(data) {
            new_cart = [];
            var obj = {};
            obj['sku'] = data.results[0].sku;
            obj['quantity'] = quantity1;
            obj['title'] = data.results[0].product_title;
                                if(custom == null){
                    obj['price'] = data.results[0].price;
                } else {
                    obj['price'] = custom.totalPrice;
                }
            obj['img'] = data.results[0].img;
            obj['url'] = data.results[0].url;
            obj['internalSku'] = data.results[0].sku;
            obj['custom'] = custom;
            new_cart.push(obj);

            var keys = Object.values(new_cart);
            console.log(keys);
        
            datatest(keys); 
})
```

Comment: what do you want as command, your syntax doesnt seem good

Comment: As result I want to use key.quantity into the getJSON function as you can see. At this moment it is variable named quantity1. This is loaded with: `obj['quantity'] = quantity1;`

Comment: i understant that, what is the command you want?? display what you want in the getjson command

Comment: Eventually take in the integer value in the object to another function. However, for the `obj ['quantity']` I have to provide the correct quantity that applied to the original cart from LocalStorage. However, I don't get that value in getJSON.

Comment: its your server which reads and understants the command.. so i dont understant your syntax.and sorry i odnt understant your problem..without a sample or better explanation

Comment: I don't understand your questions at all. It doesn't matter. The only thing I want is using a variable which is OUTSIDE the getJSON function, INTO the getJSON function.